# Change the colour of a particle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working in 1.14 and I have this particle command: `/particle minecraft:effect ~-10 ~ ~ 1 0 1 1 50`which is the particle effect for potions, the swirling bubbles.  The problem with this is that the effect will always be white.  I'd like to change the colour of this paricle, similar to what you can do with the `dust` particle, [where you use RBG codes to change the colour](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/particle).  But whenever I try to define these parameters for the effects particle, I am getting an error.  Is there a way I can change the colour of the `effect` particle specifically?

Comment: What command do you use for dust particles, when you want to change the color? How do you make them blue, and how yellow?

Comment: It uses [RGB](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/RGB-red-green-and-blue) Which are the parameters located just after "dust". It also takes a fourth parameter for the scale.  For example, this is blue: `/particle minecraft:dust 0 0 1 1 ~ ~ ~10 1 0 1 1 20`

Comment: Ok, I see, I will have to look into it a bit more. And I somehow missed that information in the link that you provided, I found it now, so sorry for asking

Comment: The 4th parameter is for the alpha channel, it decides the opacity, I guess that is what you meant with "scale"?

Comment: So far the only thing I have found would be the entity_effect instead of the effect. You cannot control the color of it either though

Comment: I meant scale.  When you increase that number you'll notice the particle elements grow larger.  When you decrease the number, they shrink.

Comment: You are right, the site you linked to is wrong, or out of date.

Comment: It appears to have been possible in 1.12 and older, but I cannotfind anything for 1.13+. And sorry for telling you, I guess you knew this already, since you asked for it and did the research already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command to make red particles:

```
/particle entity_effect ~ ~ ~10 1 0 0 1 0 normal @a
```

The syntax is

```
/particle entity_effect <location> <red> <green> <blue> <changes saturation in some way> 0 <normal|forced> <viewers>
```

Comment: So there is no way to have this work and increase the particle count?  The particle count must be 1?

Comment: You are correct, it has to be 0 though